# Issue with code format?

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I edited [some stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513664/web-xml-crashes-app) to remove the "js-snippet" markup. But after the edit, the code highlighter did not "pick up", so the code was not highlighted, I had to add `<!-- language: lang-java -->` between the text and the code to fix that.

Is that a known issue?

Comment: Looks like the XML tag is the culprit. If you remove it, then the code gets Java coloring. No idea what the rules are (if any) when two tags have highlighting preferences.

Comment: @Mat I wasn't aware tags have influence on syntax-highlighting, good to know, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way syntax highlighting language is inferred is explained in [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting):

> - If a question has no tags with a default or specific language hint, *no* syntax highlighting will be performed.
> - If a question has at most one tag with a specific language hint, plus any number of default or null hints, then syntax highlighting
>     will be performed only for that *specific* language.
> - If a question has two tags that both define specific languages, it uses *default* and lets prettify infer as it always has.
> - As long as a question has one or more tags with default language hints, but none with a specific language hint, it uses *default* and
>     let prettify infer as it always has.

You can override it as you have done with `<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->`. Since `xml` is one of the tags supported by prettify for syntax highlighting, that was the one chosen. It's not a bug. Looking at the question you linked to, the OP should've tagged the question as Java.